# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'elsharkawyazq_climate_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, laravel, cpanel

My env Database is Right but I get this error

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'elsharkawyazq_climate_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm using  laravel 5.8 on PHP 7.3  on my server

I tried other working database didn't work so env file data is correct but I don't know why this is happening

My Env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=elsharkawyazq_climate_app
DB_USERNAME=elsharkawyazq_climate_app
DB_PASSWORD=SomePassword!@##@!
```

My Database

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'elsharkawyazq_climate'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'elsharkawyazq_test'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'SomePassword!@##@!'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

i used Xampp on local and everything was fine

Comment: May be you have ran your application before changing env file. You need to change your env file first. Possible solution is to delete all files and upload them again.

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is but I dont see this set in your env file `'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),`

Comment: Any update Kareimovich?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The pound sign acts as a comment](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#comments). You cannot use the pound sign (`#`) as a character in a .env file when it is not escaped. Surround your password with quotes:

```
DB_PASSWORD="Your-password-with-###-here"
```

When I enter the `php artisan tinker` environment, I can load the environment variables from the `.env` and when I have a pound sign in a value, it acts as a comment. When put inside quotes it does not.

Answer (score 2):

In your .env DB_PASSWORD don't use any (!) and (#) character. You can use (@) or (%) character in your password. So remove these characters from your DB_password.

```
DB_PASSWORD="Use only the laravel allowed db password allowed characters"
```

I think it should work for all lavavel lovers.